# In The phrase "What in the X's name was that?" What can we use in place of X?

Tags: phrase-usage

There's this phrase, What in God's name was that? Some people use some other words, other than God. Like what in Trump-derangement-syndrome's name was that? Is it correct? What else can we use there? Does it always have to be a noun?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no "rule" about what you can put in place of "God" in that expression, anything else is replacing the word "God" either for comic "What in the name of Jean-Paul Gautier..." (because you think that Gautier has a god complex), or for euphamistic effect "What in heaven's name..."

I can't say that your example is "correct" or "incorrect".  It is certainly very odd, but it could be deliberately odd, in order to make a political joke.

Grammatically it would have to be a noun in that position and sense.

Comment: Great!! Can you tell me one or two alternate examples? I just can't get any more phrases out of google

Comment: @bruceleefinalkungfu Since the original construction involves swearing by a deity, many variations are both [euphemistic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/euphemism) and colloquial. "What in the [Sam Hill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sam_Hill_(euphemism))," "What in tarnation." See also https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/234974/what-does-in-the-name-of-actually-mean

Answer (score 0):

There are many variations of this phrase.

This one is pretty common, at least in Australia:

> What the f*** was that?

Another one I’ve heard is:

> What in the blue blazes was that?

And I really like this version from the Back to the Future movies, which featured a scientist:

> What in the name of Sir Isaac H. Newton happened here?